# How do I get a const pointer to a const struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, constants

I like to create scenarios in my code where I declare a static global struct inside a .c file that everyone will share, it contains configuration stuff. Right underneath the declaration, I'll create a constant pointer to this struct and put this in the .h file so that everyone can get access to it.

Sometimes, within a .c file, I like to have a global pointer to the specific configuration that that .c file cares about, that way I don't have constantly keep referencing the global struct, because sometimes I'll get this configuration from a different source on different projects.

The issue that I have is that I can't define this "local global" pointer because the initializer element is not constant. Here is an example.

```
typedef struct
{
    int Value;
} mystruct_t, *pmystruct_t;

static const mystruct_t GlobalStruct;
const pmystruct_t pGlobalStruct = &GlobalStruct;

const int *ValuePtr = &pGlobalStruct->Value;

int main()
{
    *ValuePtr = 10;

    return 0;
}
```

I tried reading on the const keywords for pointer in C, and I thought I understood it, but apparently it's still a mystery to me. The line of code that I tried, and may gotten me closer to that piece of code to compile is

```
const mystruct_t const *pGlobalStruct = &GlobalStruct;
```

However, it still doesn't compile because ValuePtr initializer element is not constant (the error I get).

The end goal here is to have ValuePtr be a constant, where no one can change where it is pointing to, but allow change the elements of the struct that it is pointing to.

EDIT: I want ValuePtr to use pGlobalStruct

Comment: This is just one of many reasons why we should never hide pointers behind typedef. Doing so is the root of all problems here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition

```
const pmystruct_t pGlobalStruct = &GlobalStruct;
```

makes the variable (the pointer itself) `pGlobalStruct` constant, not the structure that it points to.

This is only *one* of the many flaws that hiding pointers behind type-aliases have.

And to make the definition of `ValuePtr` valid as well, then you need to make both the pointer variable as well as the structure it points to constant:

```
const mystruct_t * const pGlobalStruct = &GlobalStruct;
```

Now `pGlobalStruct` is a constant pointer to a constant `mystruct_t` object.

Comment: Ah, I was so close... This line of code now compiles. ValuePtr now gives me issue. If I use a 'const int' then I can't change the value because it is read-only, makes sense. If i change the line of code to 'int * const ValuePtr', then I get a warning that the const qualifier is discarded. How can I change the value that ValuePtr is pointing to and not get the warning?

Comment: @Maty you cant. You told the compiler that the structure will not change and you want to change it by referencing by pointer to not const data. It is undefined behaviour in C. If you do not want to change something declare it as `const` , if you want to modify it - do not declare it as `const` - it is very simple.

Comment: @0___________ Gotcha! I removed some of the consts and it is now good. This is making a lot more sense now. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

Do not hide pointers behind the `typedef`s.

If your pointer is referencing constant object you cant assign it with the value. You can only initialize the object.

```
const int x = 10;   //initialization
cosnt int *ptr = &x;
```

> How do I get a const pointer to a const struct?
> All possible combinations below:

```
struct str
{
    int x;
    float b;
};

struct str a;
const struct str b;
const struct str *c;
struct str * const d;
const struct str * const e;
```

- `a` - not `const` structure
- `b` - `const` structure
- `c` - not `const` pointer to `const` structure
- `d` - `const` pointer to not `const` structure
- `e` - `const` pointer to `const` structure

In your case

```
const mystruct_t * const pGlobalSttruct = &GlobalStruct;
```

Comment: Thank you! That list helps. I don't know why I have a hard time with the const qualifier.